# mix `stringsAsFactors` in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to create a R dataFrame where some columns would be treated as Factors and others as Strings.

```
fruits <- data.frame(fruit = character(), descr = character())
fruits <- rbind(fruits, data.frame(fruit = "apple", descr = "jjrkgnser"))
fruits <- rbind(fruits, data.frame(fruit = "apple", descr = "aprtgh"))
fruits <- rbind(fruits, data.frame(fruit = "pear", descr = "akjreg"))
```

Here both columns are treated as Factors, and I end up with as many factors for the `descr` columns as there are rows in the `fruits` dataFrame.

How can `descr` be treated as String, but `fruit` as Factors?
If I use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` it applies to all columns!

**Edit**

I hacked this solution, not so elegant:

```
fruits <- data.frame(fruit = factor(), path = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
fruits <- rbind(fruits, data.frame(fruit = factor("apple"), path = "jjrkgnser", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
fruits <- rbind(fruits, data.frame(fruit = factor("apple"), path = "aprtgh", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
fruits <- rbind(fruits, data.frame(fruit = factor("pear"), path = "akjreg", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Doing

```
> str(fruits)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ fruit: Factor w/ 2 levels "apple","pear": 1 1 2
 $ path : chr  "jjrkgnser" "aprtgh" "akjreg"
```

fits the requirement. Is there a *nicer* way?

Comment: Use commands `as.factor` and `as.character`, if needed, for each column separately.

Comment: Are you using `rbind` as part of some script? Why not creating the whole data set at once? Something like `fruits <- data.frame(fruit = c("apple", "apple", "pear"), descr = I(c("jjrkgnser", "aprtgh", "akjreg")))`. Your code is both over-complicated and inefficient as it is growing objects without pre-allocating memory

Comment: @AntoniosK would you mind posting it as an answer? I can't figure out how.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes I'm aware of the inefficiency but I cannot easily vectorize the rest of my code. My memory footprint will be low, but your remark is excellent for other SO'ers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# creating the dataset (no usage of rbind if possible) with factor columns by default
fruits <- data.frame(fruit = c("apple", "apple", "pear"), 
                     path = c("jjrkgnser", "aprtgh", "akjreg"))

# transform this column to a character vector
fruits$path = as.character(fruits$path)
```

Comment: Good, thanks! And that works even with my growing object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're using `rbind` as an illustrative example or as a use-case (it's very memory inefficient to expand data that way), but assuming it's necessary then you can make your input a little more parsimonious using `data_frame` from the `tibble` package (in the `dplyr` et al. package ecosystem)

```
library(tibble)
fruits <- data_frame(fruit = factor(), descr = character())
fruits <- rbind(fruits, data_frame(fruit = factor("apple"), descr = "jjrkgnser"))
fruits <- rbind(fruits, data_frame(fruit = factor("apple"), descr = "aprtgh"))
fruits <- rbind(fruits, data_frame(fruit = factor("pear"), descr = "akjreg"))
```

Comment: Nice solution, I'll keep that in mind my my own use. My production environment has dplyr 0.4.3 and doesn't ship tibble yet. I don't have full control on that and would rather keep dependencies down.